# Pushing from friend's computer

Tags: github

I'm borrowing a friend's computer, and when I tried to push to my repository I got the following error.

remote: Permission to /.git denied to .
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com///': The requested URL returned error: 403

"git config user.email" and "git config user.name" show my github username/email

Comment: What exactly are you trying to push?  From where are you pushing?

Comment: I'm trying to push a xcode project (I copied the project into the local repo) from the local repo on the desktop. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Pushing your code to the remote repository on a different computer is not much different than setting up Git from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You must add your (your friend's computer) `ssh public key` to your github account.
[See this link on how to add them](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)